# how to get the id of an img tag in php variable when an image is clicked?

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

```
<a href="#"><img src="images/jbl.png" id="idhims"/></a>
<a href="#"><img src="images/swastik.png" id="idhims2" name="img2name"/></a>
```

When any one of the above image is clicked, I want to retrieve the data from `mysql` database in another `div` by using the clicked image's id.

I want to use the id of the clicked image in `SELECT`-Query to retrieve the data from mysql database.

Comment: Without javascript or jquery?

Comment: You'll need Jquery to obtain the id value and then send it to PHP using Ajax.

Comment: Php cannot do this on its own, you need client side script

Comment: whats the problem in using Ajax ? all you would have to do is send the id to the server using Ajax and the server would do the computation and send back the data from mysql database and you can add that data in another div.

Comment: PHP is unable to do this due to its core nature.  PHP simply refers to Hypertext Preprocessor.  You require some Jquery magic!

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery

include this in

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        var imgId = $(this).children('img').attr('id');// store the id to varialbe imgId
        //alert(imgId);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process_form.php",
            data: {imageid:imgId},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                //var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data); if the dataType is not specified as json uncomment this
                $("#message_ajax").html(data.frmdb);// message_ajax is the id of the container to show the returned value
            }
        });   
    });
})
```

you can access the value in your php page as `$_POST['imageid']`

sample php page which will return the value of the image clicked back to our user

```
$return_arr = array();
$return_arr['frmdb'] = $_POST['imageid'];
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

Comment: actually i don't know how to use ajax to store the javascript variable in php variable....what statement i will have to write in "put your statement here" section....as i got the id in an variable i will have to store it in a php variable ..

Comment: in your php page you run the codes to get your data from db and return that data what is to be shown to the user in preferably json format.data will have the entire response from the server page.you can do what ever you want with that.eg:show the data in a <div> or <span> still not clear?

Comment: i got the id in a variable but i don't know where and what code i need  to write to store value in php variable.

Comment: Hi !! i upload the file here http://www.yourfilelink.com/get.php?fid=833499 please take a look and let me know where i am lacking the code.. i have commented the code .....

Answer (score 1):

add the function onclick="yourFunction(this.id)", example:

```
    <script>
      function yourFunction(id) {
        alert(id);
      }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

For your query I make the jsfiddle look this in following

HTML

```
<img  src="http://google.com/img" id="id"/>
<img  src="http://google.com/img" id="id1"/>
<img  src="http://google.com/img" id="id2"/>
```

Js

```
$("img").click(function() {
  alert(this.id);
});
```

[for jsfiddle example click here](http://jsfiddle.net/9BCXG/)

Answer (score 0):

Put an action into controller to retrieve data from DB. Something like

```
public function actionQuery($id)
{
    $result=(your query using $id);
    echo CJSON::encode(array('data'=>$result));
}
```

On the page using jQuery

```
<a href="#"><img src="1" id="idhims" onclick="query(this)"/></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function query(obj) {
        $.get("your_controller/query", { id: $(obj).attr('id') })
            .done(function(data) {
                use the data to fill your div;
            });
    }
</script>
```